# Concatenate items again after applying Observable.from() operator in Rx Java

Tags: java, rx-java

I have a Observable that emits a list of **Location** objects. These Location objects have a method `getUser()` which returns a **User** (really!?). What I'm trying to do is return a new Observable that emits a list of User objects given this list of Location objects. Here's my code:

**Locations Observable**

```
 private Observable<List<QBLocation>> retrieveLocations(){

    QBLocationRequestBuilder getLocationsBuilder = new QBLocationRequestBuilder();
    getLocationsBuilder.setPerPage(100);
    getLocationsBuilder.setLastOnly();
    getLocationsBuilder.setCurrentPosition(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    getLocationsBuilder.setSort(SortField.CREATED_AT);
    getLocationsBuilder.setSort(SortField.DISTANCE, SortOrder.DESCENDING);

    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {

        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();

        try {

            ArrayList<QBLocation> qbLocations = QBLocations.getLocations(getLocationsBuilder, mBundle);
            subscriber.onNext(qbLocations);
            subscriber.onCompleted();

        } catch (QBResponseException e) {
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
    });
}
```

**User Observable**

```
@Override
public Observable<List<QBUser>> retrieveUsers() {

    return retrieveLocations()
            .flatMap(qbLocations -> Observable.from(qbLocations))
            .flatMap(qbLocation -> qbLocation.getUser())

            //How do I return an observable list with these users?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toList()` operator to collect you items back into a list:

```java
    @Override
    public Observable<List<QBUser>> retrieveUsers() {
        return retrieveLocations()
                .flatMap(qbLocations -> Observable.from(qbLocations))
                .flatMap(qbLocation -> qbLocation.getUser())
                .toList();
    }
```

Comment: if I add the `toList()`method I get a **Cyclic inference** Lint error  at `qbLocation -> qbLocation.getUser()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be simplified:

```
@Override
public Observable<List<QBUser>> retrieveUsers() {
    return retrieveLocations()
        .flatMapIterable(qbLocations -> qbLocations)
        .map(qbLocation::getUser)
        .toList();
}
```

Also, I'd rewrite your retrieveLocations as follows:

```
return Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(QBLocations.getLocations(getLocationsBuilder, mBundle));
```

Which with some static imports and exception handling becomes:

```
return defer(() -> {
   try {
     return just(getLocations(getLocationsBuilder, mBundle));
   } catch(Exeption e){
     return Observable.error(e);
   }
});
```

Abstracting the error handling will make it even easier to read:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface <T,R,E> ThrowningFunction { R apply(T t) throws E; }
@FunctionalInterface
public interface <R,E> ThrowningSupplier { R get() throws E; }

public static <T,R> Func1<T,Observable<R>> protect(ThrowningFunction<T,R,?> func) {
  return t -> {
    try {
      return Observable.just(func.apply(t));
    } catch(Exception e) {
      return Observable.error(e);
    }
  }
}

public static <R> Func0<Observable<R>> protect(ThrowningSupplier<R,?> func) {
  return () -> {
    try {
      return Observable.just(func.get());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      return Observable.error(e);
    }
  }
}
```

This makes your actual getLocations return like this:

```
return defer(() -> protect(() -> getLocations(getLocationsBuilder, mBundle)));
```

Whops, this has meandered out of control...

Comment: Or use `fromCallable` and get exception handling without the need for try-catch.